# Counting number of entries with conditions in a dataframe in R (generic)

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe with thousands of entries. I do not know the names and number of columns. How can I **count the number of elements that have exactly the same values in all columns except the last one**?

Usually I would just do:

```
nrow(subset(df, attr1 == value1 & attr2 == value2 & attr3 == value3))
```

But in this case I don't know how many are the attributes before running this code.

Consider I have all the requested values (`value1`, `value2`...) stored in the `x` variable built as follows:

```
 x = df[i,]
```

I tried with

```
nrow(subset(df, colnames(df)[1:(ncol(df) - 1)] == x[1:(ncol(df) - 1)]))
```

but this produces `0`

I add **some information on my dataset** as reference. Running this code:

```
print(x)
print(colnames(df))
print(head(df))
```

I obtain the following output:

```
377   3rd Male Adult       No
[1] "Class"    "Sex"      "Age"      "Survived"
  Class  Sex   Age Survived
1   3rd Male Child       No
3   3rd Male Child       No
4   3rd Male Child       No
5   3rd Male Child       No
6   3rd Male Child       No
7   3rd Male Child       No
```

Comment: Can you please give examples of input and corresponding expected output?

Comment: @RuiBarradas I added some information, hope it will help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function does what the question asks for.
First, it removes the last element of `x` and the last column of `DF`.
Then, `Reduce` applies function `'=='` to a list of the new `x` and of each of the rows of the new `DF`.

```
countEqual <- function(DF, X){
  X <- X[-length(X)]
  DF <- DF[-ncol(DF)]
  eq <- apply(DF, 1, function(y){
    all(Reduce('==', list(X, y)))
  })
  sum(eq)
}

x <- c("3rd", "Male", "Adult", "No")

countEqual(df, x)
#[1] 0

countEqual(df, c("3rd", "Male", "Child", "No"))
#[1] 6
```

**Test data creation code.**

This is the dataset in the question with 20 more rows.

```
df <- read.table(text = "
  Class  Sex   Age Survived
1   3rd Male Child       No
3   3rd Male Child       No
4   3rd Male Child       No
5   3rd Male Child       No
6   3rd Male Child       No
7   3rd Male Child       No                 
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

set.seed(1234)
n <- 20
Class <- sample(c("1st", "2nd", "4th"), n, TRUE)
Sex <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), n, TRUE)
Age <- sample(c("Child", "Adult"), n, TRUE)
Survived <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), n, TRUE)
df2 <- data.frame(Class, Sex, Age, Survived)

df <- rbind(df, df2)
df <- df[with(df, order(Class, Sex, Age, Survived)), ]
row.names(df) <- NULL
```